# PHP Carbon formatting day in st, nd, rd, th format

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am using PHP Carbon to format the day. I get the day of the date like this.

```
$day = Carbon::parse($date)->format('d');
```

But I want to format that day something like this.

```
'01st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th'
```

How can I do that, please?

Comment: How do you determine whether it has a trailing `0` or not (i.e. `01st` in your example but the others have no `0`)?

Comment: I don't know if that is compatible with the `date()` function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), but, you can try the `dS` format.

Comment: Thanks @IsmaelMiguel. It works.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using **DateTime** class in PHP

```
$day = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2019-06-09')->format('jS');

//Or Using Existing Carbon Class

$day = Carbon::parse($date)->format('jS');
```

For More Info DateTimeFormats in PHP [PHP Date Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can format it with `Carbon` as below

```
Carbon::parse($date)->format('dS') // with preceding 0 ie 01st
Carbon::parse($date)->format('jS') // without preceding 0 ie 1st
```

for more
[See Carbon Documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)